# Inconsistency in Mathematics of QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum, mathematics

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$
I am learning Quantum Field Theory right now and I stumbled a bit of math that buffles me a lot. In David Tong's notes on QFT, page 76, he used the following trick:

\begin{align}
\langle{\Psi}|U(t, -\infty)|0\rangle &= \langle{\Psi}|U(t, -\infty)[|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|+\sum_{n \neq 0}|n\rangle\langle n|]|0\rangle \\ &=\langle{\Psi}|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|0\rangle+ \lim_{t \to -\infty} \langle{\Psi}|[\sum_{n \neq 0} e^{-iE_{n}t} |n\rangle\langle n|]|0\rangle \\
&=\langle{\Psi}|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|0\rangle
\end{align}

where the second term was killed by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and the fact that the sum is a continuous integral over n.

My concern is that if you change the $\langle \psi|$ and $|0\rangle$ to any other normalizable state, the above argument still holds, which lead to a whole bunch of inconsistencies. For example, $$\langle{\Psi_1}|U^\dag(+\infty, -\infty) U(+\infty, -\infty)|{\Psi_1}\rangle = \langle{\Psi_1}|\Omega\rangle\langle
\Omega|{\Psi_1}\rangle,$$ which gives not 1 if $|\Psi_1\rangle$ is not ground state, so time-evolution operator is no longer unitary. All the operators in Heisenberg picture evaluated at asymptotic times $t = \pm \infty$ acting on states become acting on ground states, for example $\hat{a} \, (t = \infty)$ will annihilate what ever state it acts on. And all states at asymptotic times become ground states, so formulas such as LSZ reduction formula, which involves non-ground state at $t = \pm \infty$, $| i \rangle$ makes no sense at all...

Is this one of the situations where unrigorous math in QFT led to contradictions and if I am carefull with it, such issue is resolved? Is so, which part of math do I need  to read a bit about?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148369/50583 [but anything that involves pretending $\lvert \Omega\rangle$ and $\lvert 0\rangle$ have non-zero overlap/live in the same Hilbert space is non-rigorous anyway, cf. Haag's theorem]

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I am well aware of Haag's theorem. But even if one just restricts to free theory, where |Ω⟩ and |0⟩ coincide, this issue still exists. And in this case these is no problem with different Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Also, you can replace |0⟩ in the orginal formulas by any other normalizable state. Then the above argement should stll hold, and the free theory ground state does not even enter into the question, so I don't think |0⟩ is the problem here.

Comment: I understood your question; my comment makes two distinct points: 1. The question I linked makes a very similar point about this trick being in contradiction to unitary time evolution. 2. If you're looking for rigor, fixing this "trick" (or understanding how it makes sense here but not in general) alone does nothing to make this more rigorous since pretending that $\langle \Omega \vert 0\rangle$ is a meaningful expression in any context is non-rigorous to begin with. You need to switch your approach to perturbative QFT completely to something that does not involve the interaction picture.

Comment: As a complete outsider, but fairly serious about some of these issue, I'd strongly echo @ACuriousMind's comments. That is, there is indeed a problem already in your premise, etc. As a mathematician, these difficulties are very interesting... but that "interest" is maybe not so convenient for physicists, especially as novices. :)